# How to call Twilio carrier lookup from Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, twilio

There are a lot of posts showing how to call Twilio's carrier lookup from other languages, but not from Access VBA.   Devin Rader has a great example of how to send SMS messages from Access VBA, but I don't see how to modify that to instead do a carrier lookup.   Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume you mean [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/twilio-from-excel-and-access.html)? That does have some good base code to build from (though it is a 9 year old blog post). What have you tried so far in trying to change it to do a carrier lookup?

Comment: That's the crux of my question -- I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how the calls should change.   I assume, for example, that the URL needs to change (e.g. replacing the "/SMS/Messages").  Also, the call to setRequestHeader needs to change, as well as the contents of postData.

Comment: Yes, you would need to change the URL, you can find the path for the [lookup API here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api) (note that the phone number becomes part of the path and any parameters are passed as query string parameters). You would not need to change the `setRequestHeader`, though you would need to make the request as a `GET` request and not `POST`. If you're looking up the carrier type, you will also need to parse the response as JSON, which the blog post doesn't cover. I recommend you try something out and then if you have a problem, expand on that in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response.  I will work those suggestions.